# Define a temporary attribute in an ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I want to save a temporary attribute in an ActiveRecord model.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :order_total

  def order_total
    self[:order_total] = self.sale_sum + self.freight_charges
  end
end

order = Order.find(1)
order.order_total
```

My question is: *How can I define a virtual (aka temporary) attribute in an ActiveRecord model?*

Comment: Please, write your code as *text*, do not embed code as images.

Comment: Why not use the `order_total` as a method instead of trying to make it an attribute? This would be cleaner. None the less, you might need a setter method to get that working.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  def order_total
    sale_sum + freight_charges
  end

end

order = Order.find(1)
order.order_total # will eq to sale_sum + freight_charges
```